# ¿Cómo usar django con anaconda?

Tags: django, python-3.7

Estoy usando django por primera vez y leí en internet que para utilizarlo debía crear un entorno en anaconda y lo hice siguiendo esta página: https://pythonistaplanet.com/how-to-create-a-django-project-in-anaconda-very-easily/
Al principio me salía el error: ImportError: No module named django.core y buscando en internet leí que era porque no tenía las mismas versiones de python, por lo que desinstale python de mi computadora, ya que en mi computadora tenía instalado python 3.7.3 y en anaconda python 3.7.6. También desinstale python launcher de mi computadora. 
La cosa es que al hacer esto ya no me salió el error, pero ahora cada vez que pongo el comando: 
django-admin startproject ejemploD, solo me abre visual studio y no me crea la carpeta. No sé por qué sucede esto o cómo arreglarlo. 
¡Ayuda por favor!

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar miniconda, te sugiero revisar esta guía de instalación vía vídeo en español de miniconda, específicamente para trabajar con Django, hay un tutorial para cada sistema operativo, Windows7 y 10, MacOS y Linux lo que me parece genial! muy completo. Link: https://hcosta.github.io/instalardjango.com/

Answer (score 0):

En consola verifica que tengas instalado Django con

```
python -m django --version
```

Puede que se haya borrado cuando desinstalaste python.